# print from specific rows with highest value from multiple columns using R Studio

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have attached excellent image, I want to extract only those column in which Its row should have maximum value comparing other row

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, provide a reproducible version of your data (not a picture):

```
dput(dta)
structure(list(A = c(45, 20, 9, 6, 6), B = c(23, 34, 7, 10, 5
), C = c(12, 15, 8, 0, 4), D = c(4, 4, 6, 0, 3), E = c(5, 6, 
3, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("BOX_A", "BOX_B", 
"BOX_C", "BOX_D", "BOX_E"))
```

Now find which column is the maximum:

```
idx <- apply(dta, 1, which.max)
```

Now display the rows where the maximum is in the first column. This is not what you asked for but it is what your picture shows:

```
dta[idx==1, ]
#        A  B  C D E
# BOX_A 45 23 12 4 5
# BOX_C  9  7  8 6 3
# BOX_E  6  5  4 3 2
```

Comment: Thank you very muchfor this solution, kindly help how to display only row if equal value with column 1 (A),

Comment: I do not understand. This code locates which column contains the maximum value for each row and then prints the rows where the maximum value is in the first column. If you want the rows where the maximum value is in the second column use `dta[idx==2, ]`. You could identify the maximum values and then compare the values in column 1 to see if they are equal to the maximum. Using the function `which.max()` does this more efficiently.

Comment: You need to update your question with this new data. Show us what you want the result to look like. Columns 1 and 7 of BOX_A contain the largest value. What should happen? Try the solution on your new data and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Suppose I am having data like this

Comment: data<-structure(list(A = c(45, 20, 9, 6, 6), B = c(23, 34, 9, 10, 5), C = c(12, 15, 8, 0, 4), D = c(4, 4, 6, 0, 3), E = c(5, 20, 3, 1, 2), F= c(45, 6, 9, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("BOX_A", "BOX_B", 
                                                                                                                                                                         "BOX_C", "BOX_D", "BOX_E"))

Comment: and I want result like this, display only matched value with A

Comment: data<-structure(list(A = c(45, 20,9), B = c("NA", "NA", 9), E = c("NA",20, "NA"),F = c(45,"NA", 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("BOX_A", "BOX_B","BOX_C"))

Comment: Kindly suggest, I am having huge file

Comment: I do not understand your resulting matrix, BOX_B has two 20's, but the maximum value is 34 in Column B. BOX_E is not listed but the maximum, 6,  is in Column A? We cannot continue in the comments. You need to edit your question to reflect what you are trying to do. Move the examples from your comments to your question.